# Erro ao importar arquivo com acentos - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, codificação-de-caracteres

Galera, estou precisando copiar um arquivo físico de um diretório para outro, mas para isso preciso usar Postgres.

Estou usando as funções de LO para fazer isso. Eu consigo copiar perfeitamente o arquivo quando ele não tem acentos, mas quando tem eu recebo o seguinte erro quando executo a função no pgAdmin:

"Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed."

Já tentei executar direto no prompt de comando e o erro é esse aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O script de copiar esta aqui

```
DO $$
declare
    l_oid oid;

BEGIN
    select lo_import('c:\_anexos\anexo_pessoas_juridicas\128__Curriculos.doc') into l_oid;
    perform lo_export(l_oid, 'c:\_anexos\128__Curriculos.doc');
END $$
```

Mas o problema mesmo é na parte do lo_import